# Does can bus pinout differ in cars?

Tags: protocols, can-bus, obd-ii

I am doing research on **CAN BUS** and CAN Protocol. I want to know that, does each car model has different pinout on OBDII port? **Or Is it same on all cars?**

P.S. If it differs, is there a database for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia to the rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#Standard_interfaces):

> OBD-II is an improvement over OBD-I in both capability and standardization. The **OBD-II standard specifies the** type of diagnostic **connector** and its **pinout**, the electrical signalling protocols available, and the messaging format.

Comment: so, it means that pinout is always same since 2008 on all the car models. Is it?